# How to select only values that are not repeating in a column example if a have column with following values "A,b,c,a,c" i have to select only b

Tags: sql

How to select only values that are not repeating in a column?  For example if a have table with following values I expect to return only the `id` value of `b`:

```
id
--
a
b
c
a
c
```

Answer (score 3):

Aggregation provides one approach:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In subselecet you select values which have only one record, Than in outer select you search for all datas based on that value in subselect

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM table
             GROUP BY id
             HAVING COUNT (id) = 1)
```